# What's the meaning of 'adventure'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Every year on Dudley's birthday, his parents took him and a friend out for the day, to **adventure** parks, hamburger restaurants, or the movies. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is there no chance to read ‘adventure’ as a verb? If yes, what’s the meaning of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case read it as adjective. An *adventure park* is a kind of *theme park*, like Disneyland.

Yes, "Adventure" can be read as a verb, meaning "engage in daring or risky activity" but it's not used like that in this case - this *to* should be read as *to a location*, not *to perform an activity*.

Comment: [A dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adventure) says 'adventure' has the meaning of "To venture upon; undertake or try." : 'To try parks, hamburger restaurants, or the movies' can't this be proper in meaning?

Comment: @Listenever: Gramatically, yes, but not in this sense. You adventure something dangerous. You may adventure an X-rated movies in a seedy part of town, a hamburger restaurant where local gangers gather to drink, or a park at night, where bandits and rapists roam. Not an activity for a kid to do on their birthsday.

Comment: @Listenever [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_park) is an article on *adventure parks*. SF. is correct in saying you should read *adventure* here as a adjective; but it is more likely that the phrase originates in using the **noun** adventure as an adjective.